# Defining Foreign Keys EF Code First Model

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am confused about defining foreign keys in a 1:m relationship with EF Code First Approach.

Looking through various tutorials, I see various ways of doing it - not sure what the difference is.

- [MVC Music Store Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-4)
- [CodeFirst.Codeplex.com](http://codefirst.codeplex.com/)
- [Creating an EF Data Model](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Let's assume that I have 2 models, `Product` and `Category` where 1 category has many products.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Method 1a
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories {get; set; }

    // Method 1b
    public virtual List<Category> Categories {get; set; }

    // Method 1c
    public Category Category {get; set; }

    // Method 1d
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Method 2a
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    // Method 2b
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    // Method 2c
    public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }

    // Method 2d
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ExampleContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

Product Table:
I assume that it doesn't make a difference if I use `ICollection` / `List`, but when to use 1a/1b, 1c or 1d?

Category Table:
I assume that it doesn't make a difference if I use `ICollection` / `List`, but when to use 2a, 2b, 2c?

Answer (score 0):

### **1a-d**

As `Product` - `Category` is `1 : n` it should be 1c or 1d.

Whether or not to make the property `virtual` is up to you. If you want it to be lazy loading it should be virtual. If you always use eager loading (e.g. `Include`) you may omit the `virtual` modifier.

### **2a-d**

It could be any of the options you show.

EF is totally happy with

```
public (virtual) ICollection<Category> Categories {get; set; }
```

Again, it's up to you whether you want to enable lazy loading.

There is no need to enforce an `ICollection<T>` implementation like `List<T>`. You'll often see that the property is defined as `ICollection<T>` and that the concrete type will be `List<T>` or `HashSet<T>`. As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) the latter provides high-performance set operations. You can initialize the concrete collection in the constructor of the entity.

You don't have to define both `Product.Category` and `Category.Products` to express the association. It depends on your business logic which properties you need.